# How do I display the content of the div in master file in real-time on another client file?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, socket.io, reveal.js

This is my master file which contains the slide presentation. I want to make it so that when I edit the content (in the div class="slides"), it will get displayed in real-time on the client side. How can this be done? I've tried Server sent events but it did not work.

```
<div class="contents">
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class='slides'>          //the div content can be edited
                <section id="transitions" >                      
                    <div class="editor" contenteditable="true" >
                        New Slide                                
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Client side

```
<div class="contents">
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class='slides'>             //the content in the div will be displayed in real-time
                <section id="transitions" >
                    <div class="editor" contenteditable="true" >
                        New Slide                                
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean, but dynamic content can be created using JQuery and Javascript.

```js
$("#createButton").click(function() {
    if($("#createHTML").val() != "") {
      $("#creationArea").append("" + $("#createHTML").val() + "");
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <span style="float:left">Type in HTML into text box (try creating a span with style="color:green")</span>
      <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="createHTML" style="float:left"/>
    <input type="button" id="createButton" value="create HTML"     style="float:left"/>
      <br><br>
    <div id="creationArea" style="float:left">
    </div>
    
   </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: For example, type in <div style="width:100px;height:40px;background-color:blue">Here is a div</div> to the field

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently, I have no problem creating a dynamic content. The problem that I'm facing is updating the dynamic content to other html file (the client html file) in real-time. That's what I'm trying to do to the presentation on the client-side. I've used ajax and jquery. The codes that I've written requires me to save the file first then only I can update it at the client side.

Comment: @MuhamadSyahirMohdHashim ahh, I see.  I will have a second answer as I think I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Look there : https://github.com/coffee-mug/tornado-sockjs-revealjs It will allow you to have your presentation updated in realtime on every kind of devices as you want :)

Disclaimer: I am the owner of the repo :p It uses python Tornado for the backend but you can do exactly the same thing with javascript if you prefer. It's simple : I just adapted the code (full JS) of that tutorial to make it work with Tornado : http://www.sitepoint.com/create-multi-user-presentation-reveal-js/

Hope it'll help. By the way, if you eventually decide to use my repo, do not hesitate to ask me for help or to criticize it :)